# Getting the first index of an array of objects using a property - swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I have an array of objects called `modelArray` these objects have a property which is called `timestamp` which is of type `FIRTimestamp`.

Knowing that we have another timestamp which we are gonna call `comparingTimestamp`

I'm trying to figure out how I can find the first index in the array where the property `timestamp` is `>` of the `comparingTimestamp`.

If you are not practical with firebase, the object `Timestamp` has a numerical property called `seconds` which we can use for making the comparison.

Until now I tried using the function `where` but without any good result.

Comment: Add your code, show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: what is the type of `comparingTimestamp` ?

Comment: is still "FIRTimestamp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use collection's [`firstIndex(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex) method:

---

```
struct Item {
    let timestamp: FIRTimestamp
}
```

---

```
let modelArray = [item1, item2, item3, item4]
let firstIndex = modelArray.firstIndex { item in
    item.timestamp.seconds > comparingTimestamp.seconds
}

print(firstIndex!)
```